# Steady transonic gas flow.Nonlinear PDE giving initial condition and boundary value errors

Tags: differential-equations

I wish to use `NDSolve` to solve the following  partial differential equation:

$$\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\,\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$$

Where $v$ is speed of sound `343.21` and the boundary conditions being $\{u(0,y)=0,u(1,y)=0,u(x,0)=\sin (\pi  x),u(x,1)=0\} $

Here's the code I intend to run in order to perform everything I want on it:

```
eq = (1/343.21)*D[u[x, y], {x, 1}]*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0;
bc = {u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 0, u[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x], u[x, 1] == 0};

sol = 
  NDSolve[{eq, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> 
     {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
        {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 100}}}]
```

I get the error message:

> NDSolveValue::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable. >>

**UPDATE 13.02.2017:**

Background information to the equation can be found [Here1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.4189.pdf) and [Here 2](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930082946.pdf)

Comment: The boundary conditions are not consistent  in the point (1,0). What about trying u(x,0) = Sin[pi x]?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze .With u(x,0) = Sin[pi x] the same errors. :(

Comment: Can you add some background information for the equation?

Comment: @xzczd.I'm updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution. NSolve is not able to solve the non-linear equation (in my version 10), but we study some simple linear cases in order to solve the issue of boundary and initial conditions. Finally we propose a method to find a solution of the non-linear solution.

Let us first study similar cases in which the problem has solutions.
We consider linearized equations of hyperbolic type (wave equation) and elliptic type (Laplace equation).

The boundary conditions in $x$ are as given in the OP, we call the complementary condition initial condition taken from the wave equation picture, and choose a simple sine function:

```
eq = D[u[x, t], {x, 1}]*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 
  0; (* non-liner equation of the OP *)
eq1 = D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0; (* wave equation *)
eq2 = D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0; (* Laplace equation *)
bc1 = {(* boundary conditions *) u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0,(* 
   initial condition *) u[x, 0] == Sin[\[Pi] x]};

sol1 = NDSolve[{eq1, bc1}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}][[1]];
uu1[x_, t_] := u[x, t] /. sol1[[1]];
Plot3D[uu1[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "wave equation"]
```

[image]

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{eq2, bc1}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}][[1]];
uu2[x_, t_] := u[x, t] /. sol2[[1]];
Plot3D[uu2[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Laplace equation", AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}]
```

[image]

The treatment of the non-linear equation is very brief (in my version 10)

```
sol = NDSolve[{eq, bc1}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}][[1]]
```

> During evaluation of In[101]:= NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear
>   coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve. >>

It would be interesting to study analytically the ansatz

```
u[x_, t_] := Sum[a[n, t] Sin[n \[Pi] x], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

i.e. trying to solve the system of equations for `a[n,t].`

Comment: Laplace equation is elliptic?

Comment: @MMM Yes, of course:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**.

Let us consider the two-dimensional nonlinear PDE equations:
$$\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\,\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$$
and the boundary conditions being:

$\{u(x,0)=\text{f1}(x),u(x,1)=\text{f2}(x),u(0,y)=\text{f3}(y),u(1,y)=\text{f4}(y)\}$

where:$\text{f1}(x)=\sin (\pi  x),\text{f2}(x)=0,\text{f3}(y)=0,\text{f4}(y)=0$

defined in the domain $D=\{a\leq x\leq b,c\leq y\leq d\}$ .

[image]

The finite difference schemes take the form.

$\left(\frac{U(i+1,j)}{h^2}-\frac{2 U(i,j)}{h^2}+\frac{U(i-1,j)}{h^2}\right)
   \left(\frac{U(i+1,j)}{h}-\frac{U(i,j)}{h}\right)+\frac{U(i,j+1)}{k^2}-\frac{2
   U(i,j)}{k^2}+\frac{U(i,j-1)}{k^2}$

```
{nD = 20, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 1, nX = 20, nY = 20, 
h = (b - a)/nX, k = (d - c)/nY};
xN = Table[x[i] -> a + i*h, {i, 0, nX}];
yN = Table[y[j] -> c + j*k, {j, 0, nY}];
fd[i_, j_] :=(1/343.21) (U[i + 1, j]/h^2 - 2*U[i, j]/h^2 + U[i - 1, j]/h^2)*(U[i + 1, j]/h - U[i, j]/h) + (U[i, j + 1]/k^2 - 2*U[i, j]/k^2 + U[i, j - 1]/k^2);
f1[i_] := Sin[Pi*i*h];
f2[i_] := 0;
f3[j_] := 0;
f4[j_] := 0;
bc = Flatten[{Table[U[i, 0] -> f1[i], {i, 0, nX}], 
Table[U[i, nY] -> f2[i], {i, 0, nX}], 
Table[U[0, j] -> f3[j], {j, 0, nY}], 
Table[U[nX, j] -> f4[j], {j, 0, nY}]}];
eqs = Flatten[Table[fd[i, j] == 0, {i, 1, nX - 1}, {j, 1, nY - 1}]];
eqs1 = Rationalize[Flatten[eqs /. bc], 0];
vars = Flatten[Table[{U[i, j], 0}, {i, 1, nX - 1}, {j, 1, nY - 1}], 1];
sole = FindRoot[eqs1, vars, MaxIterations -> 200] // Quiet;
points = Table[{x[i], y[j], U[i, j]}, {i, 0, nX}, {j, 0, nY}];
points1 = Flatten[N[points /. xN /. yN /. bc /. sole, nD], 1];
g = Interpolation[points1, Method -> "Hermite"];
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Method 2.**

By adding a time derivative to an elliptic PDE,  and obtaining the steady-state solution (by waiting for the process may reach a steady state).

```
tF = 20;
eq1 = 1/343.21*D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}]*D[u[x, y, t], {x, 1}] +
D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}] == D[u[x, y, t], t];
bc1 = {u[0, y, t] == 0, u[1, y, t] == 0, u[x, 0, t] == Sin[Pi*x], 
u[x, 1, t] == 0, u[x, y, 0] == Sin[Pi*x]};
sole2 = NDSolve[{eq1, bc1}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tF},
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" 
-> {"TensorProductGrid",  "MaxPoints" -> 20}}]
Plot3D[u[x, y, tF] /. sole2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel 
-> Automatic, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

The result is the same as in **Method 1**.

[image]

Comment: @xzczd.OK my mistake.

Comment: I just want to point out that, after $v$ is adding to the equation, the influence of the nonlinear term becomes very weak, now the result almost doesn't change even if `D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}]*D[u[x, y, t], {x, 1}]` is removed from the equation…

Comment: @xzczd. Can You give a better answer from mine ? :P

Comment: This is currently beyond my reach. The lack of background information is fatal, I think. (I saw your update in the question, it helps, but still not enough… ) It seems to be so hard to find materials related to this equation, strange.